# Where to store locataion data?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a scenario where there is a class/model for a 'Post'. Each post has a caption, an image ,..., and also the unique location-data (address, GeoPoints).

I am now unsure where to store these address data in Google Firestore.
Should those be appended to each document in 'Post' or should a seperate collection called 'Address' be created for this and just store the reference from 'Post' to 'Address'?

Are there some advantages or disadvantages for either possibility?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to store it along with the post data. So while fetching you will get all the data altogether. and use geoPoint datatype to store.